# filter a specific fields with the input arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter

previously I used many aggregations finally i got an output like I mentioned below, at present I want to exact the data based on my input values as I mentioned in the input array.

```
  [

    {
        "_id":"121233445543234455 " 
        "chance":[
                 {      
                    "inked":"symbol"
                    "aim":"work"
                   }
                     {      
                         "inked":"lol"
                        "aim":"jump"
                   }
                  {      
                      "inked":"alpa"
                     "aim":"going"
                   }
                  ]
              }
                  {
     "_id":"12123344gfdg " 
      "chance":[
               {      
             "inked":"symbol"
             "aim":"work"
             }
              {      
              "inked":"lol"
               "aim":"jump"
            }
           {      
            "inked":"not to say"
             "aim":"everthing done"
            }

           ]
     "_id":zzzkzikzzkzi " 
      "chance":[
               {      
             "inked":"elment"
             "aim":"h20"
             }
              {      
              "inked":"latpm"
               "aim":"sci"
            }
           {      
            "inked":"trim"
             "aim":"acces"
            }

           ]
     }
  ]
```

input is changer: I am using the postman to post the input values, i am planning to change the input ,

```
      {
       charger:["symbol,", "not to say",]

        }
```

i am getting an output like this

```
       {  
         "id" :"121233445543234455 "
         "inked":"symbol"
         "aim":"work"
       }
      {  
         "id" :"12123344gfdg "
          "inked":"not to say"
          "aim":"everything done"
           }

        {
       "_id":zzzkzikzzkzi " 
      "chance":[]
      }
```

but i need output like this, i don't want an extra id that is not with those arrays .

```
       {  
         "id" :"121233445543234455 "
         "inked":"symbol"
         "aim":"work"
       }
      {  
         "id" :"12123344gfdg "
          "inked":"not to say"
          "aim":"everything done"
           }
```

up to know i used this

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
        chance: {
            $let: {
            vars: {
                chanceInput: [
                
                changer
                ]
                },
            in: {
                "$filter": {
                "input": "$chance",
                "as": "c",
                "cond": {
                    "$in": [
                    "$$c.inked",
                    "$$chanceInput"
                    ]
                }
             }
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    ])
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` for charger as `$` is for referring to the field in the document, just provide the array such `chanceInput: charger`, which charger is your input array.

Comment: problem solved, but I am with another issue now, If I entered the input array with some other array which is not in the data, I am with an out put like id: "121233445543234455 " chance[  ], but I need about put like null which means it should not project any id and any values